# Does NativeScript work with any real-time .js frameworks?

Tags: nativescript

I'm looking to develop a real-time NativeScript app.  However, I haven't been able to identify a real-time framework that will work with NativeScript.

1. SignalR's javascript client has a dependency on jQuery, so that's out.
2. socket.io doesn't seem to be an option based on the answer to this post: 
   [NativeScript and socket.io](http://www.telerik.com/forums/nativescript-and-socket-io)

Is there any known solution to this short of rolling my own?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a WebSocket module for NativeScript which uses the native WebSocket implementation on both platforms. It can be found here https://www.npmjs.com/package/nativescript-websockets

Comment: As for already built frameworks, it looks like Socket.io is doing some work with {N}: http://socket.io/blog/socket-io-1-4-5/

Answer (score -1):

Have you checked out NativeScript's Firebase plugin? It works quite well: https://www.nativescript.org/blog/ignite-your-app-development-with-nativescript-and-firebase

Comment: This looks really interesting, though it may be a bit heavy for my purposes.  This would bring along a db when all that's needed here is a realtime communication solution.